How can one have PEP-342 style coroutines where suspending execution and moving to the other context looks like a function call on both ends?
Python generators allow program flow to jump back and forth between two different places, with messages being passed between using .send and yield as per PEP-342. For example:
def coroutine(lst):
    x = yield
    lst.append(f"{x=}")
    y = yield
    lst.append(f"{y=}")
    yield


def func():
    lst = []
    coro = coroutine(lst)
    next(coro)
    coro.send(1)
    coro.send(2)
    return lst

Here, calling func() will return ['x=1', 'y=2']. Program flow begins in func but flips back and forth between the body of func and the body of coroutine as the program continues in accordance with the semantics defined in PEP 342. Note that the word "coroutine" as used in that PEP (and in my example here) means something very different to modern awaitable coroutines; this functionality has been in the language since 2005, and involves no actual concurrency.
I want a setup that will have this same effect semantically, but where the operation "suspend execution and move to the other context, possibly with a message" looks like a function call from both ends. For example:
@magical_coroutine_decorator
def coroutine(lst):
    x = get_thing()
    lst.append(f"{x=}")
    y = get_thing()
    lst.append(f"{y=}")


def func():
    lst = []
    coro = coroutine(lst)
    coro.send(1)
    coro.send(2)
    return lst

What implementation of magical_coroutine_decorator and get_thing will have the semantics I'm looking for? Is there a library somewhere that already does this?

Where shall/can get_thing be defined?

Why do you want to do this? What's the issue with the normal way?

I don't particularly care where I have to define get_thing in order to make this work. If it has to be a bound method of some magical coordination object (which would be passed into coroutine), that's also fine.

As for the why, in context get_thing is called many layers deep into some logic that doesn't even know it's being run as a coroutine--it just calls get_thing when it wants a thing. Sometimes get_thing gets a thing by prompting the user, sometimes it runs some other computation, sometimes it sends a network request, and sometimes it should retrieve a message from a totally different application context with its own loop, here represented by func and its repeated calls to coro.send.

Turns out the Greenlet library does exactly this. From their blurb:

A “greenlet”, on the other hand, is a still more primitive notion of micro-thread with no implicit scheduling; coroutines, in other words.  [...] For example, we can recreate generators; the difference with Python’s own generators is that our generators can call nested functions and the nested functions can yield values too. (Additionally, you don’t need a “yield” keyword. [...])

And indeed, the following completes my toy example:
import greenlet

def coroutine(lst, coro):
    x = coro.switch()
    lst.append(f"{x=}")
    y = coro.switch()
    lst.append(f"{y=}")

def func():
    lst = []
    coro = greenlet.greenlet(coroutine)
    coro.switch(lst, greenlet.getcurrent())
    coro.switch(1)
    coro.switch(2)
    return lst

